Radio button not returning any values in tkinter python
this is a small part of my code which for some reason isnt working, the radio button - user_ans more specifically always return none, when before it returned the actual response- i have no idea what happened and i cant revert it. here is the code.
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.ttk import *
import tkinter
from time import *
import time
import PIL
from PIL import *

#----       ----#
Qright = 0
Qwrong = 0
current_question = 0
pink = 0

def Quizz():
    global pink
    menu.withdraw()
    # define question dictionary
    question = {
        "2+3": ['2', '3', '5', '9'],
        "2-1": ['2', '1', '4'],
        "3+3": ['3', '6', '9', '7'],
        "2+5": ['2', '3', '7', '9'],
        "2-2": ['2', '1', '0'],
        "3+1": ['3', '6', '4', '7'],
        "2+6": ['2', '3', '8', '9'],
        "2-6": ['2', '1', '-4'],
        "3+6": ['3', '6', '9', '7'],
        "3+2": ['3', '6', '5', '7']

    }
    # define answer list
    ans = ['5', '1', '6', '7', '0', '4', '8', '-4', '9', '5']




    def start_quiz():
        print("stage6")
        start_button.forget()
        print("stage7")
        next_button.pack(pady = 10)
        print("stage8")
        next_question()


    def next_question():
        print("stage9")
        global current_question
        if current_question < len(question):
            print("stage10")
            # get key or question that need to be printed
            check_ans()
            print("stage14")
            user_ans.set('None')
            print("stage15")
            c_question = list(question.keys())[current_question]
            print("stage16")
            # clear frame to update its content
            clear_frame()
            print("stage17")
            # printing question
            Label(f1, text=f"Question : {c_question}", font="calibre 12 normal").pack(anchor=NW)

            print("stage18")
            # printing options
            for option in question[c_question]:
                print("stage19")
                Radiobutton(f1, text=option, variable=user_ans, value=option).pack(anchor=NW)               
                print("stage20")
                print(user_ans.get())
            print("-")
            print(user_ans.get())
            print("-")
            current_question += 1
        else:
            next_button.forget()
            check_ans()
            clear_frame()
            output = f"Your Score is {user_score.get()} out of {len(question)}"
            Label(f1, text=output, font="calibre 25 bold").pack()
            Label(f1, text="Thanks for Participating",font="calibre 18 bold").pack()
            
            '''f = open("results.txt", "a")
            f.write(f"\n {user_score.get()}/{len(question)}")
            f.close()
            exit_button = Button(root, text="Return to menu", command=lambda:[deiconify,root.destroy]) 
            exit_button.pack(pady=20)'''




            


    def check_ans():
        print("stage11")
        temp_ans = user_ans.get()
        print("stage12")
        print(temp_ans)
        print(ans[current_question-1])
        if temp_ans != 'None' and temp_ans == ans[current_question-1]:
            print("stage13")
            user_score.set(user_score.get()+1)
        else:
            return


    def clear_frame():
        for widget in f1.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        print("stage0")
        root = Tk()
        print("stage1")
        # setup basic window
        root.title("Main Quiz")
        root.geometry("850x520")
        root.minsize(800, 400)
        root.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor', '#000001')

        user_ans = StringVar()
        user_ans.set('None')
        user_score = IntVar()
        user_score.set(0)
        print("stage2")
        print(pink)
        if pink == 0:
            Label(root, text="Quiz", font="calibre 20 bold").pack()#could add background="colour"
        else:
            Label(root, text="Quiz", font="calibre 20 bold",background=("pink")).pack()#could add background="colour"
            root.configure(background='pink')

        print("stage3")
        #Label(root, text="", font="calibre 10 bold").pack()
        print("stage4")
        start_button = Button(root, text="Start Quiz",command=start_quiz)
        start_button.pack(pady = 10)
        print("stage5")
        f1 = Frame(root)
        f1.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

        next_button = Button(root, text="Next Question",command=next_question)

        root.mainloop()

Ive tried to replace the radio button but i need to use it.
ive tried replacing check_ans with a new function and other options but nothing is working. I just cant fix it and this will take ages to fix i am just a student and all my searches are returning solutions with ttk.Radiobutton which i think doesnt apply to me. My code is very specific and its hard to search so i just need personal oppinions. Thanks!

Can you try to pare this down to a [mre] please? It's also worth mentioning that you don't need the * imports in addition to the regular imports. Typically you'd use import tkinter as tk and prefix widgets with tk., e.g. tk.Label, and from tkinter import ttk for ttk access. Likewise you don't need from time import * or from PIL import * - you're better off with just import time and import PIL

You have reset user_ans to None between stage14 and stage15 inside next_question().

I could't see if the user_ans value set correctly because you set them 'None' sometimes i am not sure if you set it on any other part of the code.
You can try the command param of the RadioButton in tkinter like below:
Add this method first:
def on_radio_button_selected():
    print("CHECK: Selected option is: ", user_ans.get())

Than change radio button code as below:
Radiobutton(f1, text=option, variable=user_ans, value=option, command=on_radio_button_selected).pack(anchor=NW)               


After that when you click on a radio button it should log its value. Than you can see the problem if it is with the option or variable or you can just manage the value in the on_radio_button_selected function.


this is a small part of my code which for some reason isnt working,
the radio button - user_ans more specifically always return none, when
before it returned the actual response

tried replacing check_ans with a new function and other options but
nothing is working


The problem can be fixed.
Comment out Quizz() function. So you can see Radiobutton on fly.
#def Quizz():
    #global pink
    #menu.withdraw()
    # define question dictionary
question = {
    "2+3": ['2', '3', '5', '9'],
    "2-1": ['2', '1', '4'],
    "3+3": ['3', '6', '9', '7'],
    "2+5": ['2', '3', '7', '9'],
    "2-2": ['2', '1', '0'],
    "3+1": ['3', '6', '4', '7'],
    "2+6": ['2', '3', '8', '9'],
    "2-6": ['2', '1', '-4'],
    "3+6": ['3', '6', '9', '7'],
    "3+2": ['3', '6', '5', '7']

}
# define answer list
ans = ['5', '1', '6', '7', '0', '4', '8', '-4', '9', '5']

You're ready to go.
Screenshot:

Here is completed code. Using Python 3.12.4.
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
 
 
#----       ----#
Qright = 0
Qwrong = 0
current_question = 0
pink = 0

 
# define question dictionary
question = {
    "2+3": ['2', '3', '5', '9'],
    "2-1": ['2', '1', '4'],
    "3+3": ['3', '6', '9', '7'],
    "2+5": ['2', '3', '7', '9'],
    "2-2": ['2', '1', '0'],
    "3+1": ['3', '6', '4', '7'],
    "2+6": ['2', '3', '8', '9'],
    "2-6": ['2', '1', '-4'],
    "3+6": ['3', '6', '9', '7'],
    "3+2": ['3', '6', '5', '7']

}
# define answer list
ans = ['5', '1', '6', '7', '0', '4', '8', '-4', '9', '5']

def start_quiz():
    print("stage6")
    start_button.forget()
    print("stage7")
    next_button.pack(pady = 10)
    print("stage8")
    next_question()


def next_question():
    print("stage9")
    global current_question
    if current_question < len(question):
        print("stage10")
        # get key or question that need to be printed
        check_ans()
        print("stage14")
        user_ans.set('None')
        print("stage15")
        c_question = list(question.keys())[current_question]
        print("stage16")
        # clear frame to update its content
        clear_frame()
        print("stage17")
        # printing question
        Label(f1, text=f"Question : {c_question}", font="calibre 12 normal").pack(anchor=NW)

        print("stage18")
        # printing options
        for option in question[c_question]:
            print("stage19")
            Radiobutton(f1, text=option, variable=user_ans, value=option).pack(anchor=NW)               
            print("stage20")
            print(user_ans.get())
        print("-")
        print(user_ans.get())
        print("-")
        current_question += 1
    else:
        next_button.forget()
        check_ans()
        clear_frame()
        output = f"Your Score is {user_score.get()} out of {len(question)}"
        Label(f1, text=output, font="calibre 25 bold").pack()
        Label(f1, text="Thanks for Participating",font="calibre 18 bold").pack()
        
        '''f = open("results.txt", "a")
        f.write(f"\n {user_score.get()}/{len(question)}")
        f.close()
        exit_button = Button(root, text="Return to menu", command=lambda:[deiconify,root.destroy]) 
        exit_button.pack(pady=20)'''

def check_ans():
    print("stage11")
    temp_ans = user_ans.get()
    print("stage12")
    print(temp_ans)
    print(ans[current_question-1])
    if temp_ans != 'None' and temp_ans == ans[current_question-1]:
        print("stage13")
        user_score.set(user_score.get()+1)
    else:
        return

def clear_frame():
    for widget in f1.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("stage0")
    root = Tk()
    print("stage1")
    # setup basic window
    root.title("Main Quiz")
    root.geometry("850x520")
    root.minsize(800, 400)
    root.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor', '#000001')

    user_ans = StringVar()
    user_ans.set('None')
    user_score = IntVar()
    user_score.set(0)
    print("stage2")
    print(pink)
    if pink == 0:
        Label(root, text="Quiz", font="calibre 20 bold").pack()#could add background="colour"
    else:
        Label(root, text="Quiz", font="calibre 20 bold",background=("pink")).pack()#could add background="colour"
        root.configure(background='pink')

    print("stage3")
    #Label(root, text="", font="calibre 10 bold").pack()
    print("stage4")
    start_button = Button(root, text="Start Quiz",command=start_quiz)
    start_button.pack(pady = 10)
    print("stage5")
    f1 = Frame(root)
    f1.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

    next_button = Button(root, text="Next Question",command=next_question)

    root.mainloop()


What is your OS platform?  And Python version.
